# How to create dictionary of dictionaries from python tuples

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary, tuples

I would like to create dictionary of the format in the example below.

```
c={
    'A':{('AB',2.9)},
    'B':{('AS',3.9)},
    'R':{('D',2.0)},
    'V':{('AD',2.9)},
    'G':{('AX',2.9)}
 }
```

I have this tuples feed in a loop. Here is what I have tried but I get a wrong format from this.

```
my_tuple  = ('AB',2.9)
c         = {}
my_key    = 'A'
c.update({my_key:{my_tuple}})
```

For this specific case I would like to get `{'A': set([('AB', 2.9)])}`. I understand this is a proper dictionary but how can do it better and return value of `c` in a format?. I want i.e.:

```
{'A': {('AB', 2.9)}}
```

Comment: Are you telling us that you are annoyed by the representation of a `set`?

Comment: Not at all.For simplicity and easy integration, my requirements demands that I output data in this format, otherwise I am comfortable with set. @root Is there a way of eliminating the set and have {} in place?It can help.thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need to change the `set representation`?

Comment: Are you trying to serialize your data in that format (for transferring it to somewhere else?) If so, use JSON instead.

Comment: Yes @root. I would to eliminate the set and retain my format

Answer (score 2):

`s = {1, 2, 3}` is a shorter way to declare  `s = set([1,2,3])`

Hence, you've already got what you want, it's just a representation matter.

```
>>> {('AB',2.9)} == set({('AB',2.9)})
True
```

Comment: I think I am missing something. What you have done is correct. How do I now present my set({('AB',2.9)}) to {('AB',2.9)}. This result is going to a file and it has to be written as {('AB',2.9)} no set

Comment: If representation is all you require, I'd suggest you refer to @Abhijit's answer, which does exactly what you want, by defining the ``__repr__`` method of a child class of ``set``.

Answer (score 1):

If representation is all that matters to you, you can inherit from `set` and create your own version of `__repr__` which will give you the freedom of using your imagination to satisfy you :-)

```
>>> class funky_set(set):
    def __new__(cls,*args):
        return set.__new__(cls,args)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{{{}}}".format(','.join(map(str, self)))

>>> my_tuple  = ('AB',2.9)
>>> c         = {}
>>> my_key    = 'A'
>>> c.update({my_key:funky_set(my_tuple)})
>>> c
{'A': {AB,2.9}}
```